# "Shut my mouth wide open!"

Tags: slang

"What is origin of the expression "Shut my mouth wide open."?
Google search for the phrase produced nothing of interest.

Comment: Is it an expression? I've never heard it before. Can you show an example of its use?

Comment: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/shut-(one's)-mouth-wide-open

Comment: It appears it is a rare slang expression: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/shut-(one's)-mouth-wide-open

Comment: You can look up the origin of each word in a dictionary; why do you think the phrase has an origin separate from those?

Comment: Pace the link others have posted, I suspect that OP's "my" version is the more current than that link's imperative version with "your." As such--and I'm guessing here--it is an oxymoronic combination of the exclamation "Well, shut my mouth!" (used as an expression of surprise) and the association of intense surprise with a wide-open mouth (which is probably also behind the expression "Well, shut my mouth!").

Comment: Rare, but its abbreviation SMMWO is used in SMS exhanges!

Comment: Presumably somehow related to _eyes wide shut_ (with or without Tom Cruise).

Comment: @TimLymington: Because taken literally, it's an oxymoron (to make it make sense,  you would have to imagine a missing "which is"  :  Shut my mouth [which is] wide open.)  So it must be an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression of amazement used by the character "Kingfish" on the "Amos and Andy Show".

Comment: While this may be true, a little corroboration for those who have never heard of "Kingfish" or the *Amos and Andy Show* would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

That was an expression my Dad (now age 93) used when I was growing up in Central Texas.  I also heard it once in a move made in the late 1930s or early 1940s.  The actor who said it was a pre-teen African American boy, and it was part of a rhyme that I no longer remember.